# Как выгрузить результат работы фонового метода в базу или вернуть объект, запущенного с помощью Hangfire в ASP MVC

Tags: c#, android-asynctask, lambda

Вызываю метод объекта через Hangfire

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue((() => job.SomeMethod(arg)));
```

Как я понимаю метод будет выполняться в отдельном процессе, а параметр arg сериализуется. Как из метода SomeMethod написать что-то в базу, например, обратиться к какому-нибудь репозиторию или вернуть объект-результат?